# Gradle task assembleDebug failed with Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, sdk

I have installed flutter in Windows 10, after inserting an SSD in my old laptop. Previously, without the SSD, it was running fine (I don't very well remember what I did to make it run fine, but it was not much of a problem back then). Now, however it is not running.

After lot of work, I realized by android SDK is working fine, which means I can run android applications easily. I can also build my flutter code to android, which I am then running from Android studio as a hack. Note that I downloaded everything from Android Studio, including emulator, platform tools, SDK tools, and so on. (except flutter). As seen from the output, the build is working fine, but the 'assembleDebug' part of the Gradle task is not working from flutter (**independently it is working**). Something is probably wrong with how 'flutter run' works. The issue can be due to something as a missing library. If anyone can help, please do.

Also, I simply could not download from android studio the sdk commandline tools properly. Some files were missing and so on. So I manually downloaded them, to accept licenses.

**OUTPUT**:

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 31s
[   +1 ms] 144 actionable tasks: 6 executed, 138 up-to-date
[  +21 ms] Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... (completed in 31.7s)
[   +8 ms] Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code -1
[   +5 ms] "flutter run" took 33,777ms.

#0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:14:3)
#1      RunCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart:569:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      FlutterCommand.verifyThenRunCommand
(package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:723:18)
#3      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1192:38)
#4      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1085:19)
#5      _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:141:18)
#6      Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:682:45)    
#7      Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:711:32)
#8      Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:526:5)
#9      _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:36:15)
#10     _completeOnAsyncReturn (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:298:13)
#11     RunCommand.usageValues (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart)
#12     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1192:38)
#13     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1085:19)
#14     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:141:18)
#15     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:682:45)    
#16     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:711:32)
#17     Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:526:5)
#18     _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:36:15)
#19     _completeOnAsyncReturn (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:298:13)
#20     AndroidDevice.isLocalEmulator (package:flutter_tools/src/android/android_device.dart)    
#21     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1192:38)
#22     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1085:19)
#23     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:141:18)
#24     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:682:45)    
#25     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:711:32)
#26     Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:526:5)
#27     Future._asyncComplete.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future_impl.dart:556:7)
#28     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1184:13)
#29     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1077:19)
#30     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:979:7)
#31     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1019:23)       
#32     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:43:21)
#33     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:52:5)
#34     _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:118:13)
#35     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:169:5)
```

As you can see it is building correctly, but not running the gradle task. I could still work on flutter api, but then I cannot hot reload, and it is making development a painstaking process. Processes such as bundleRelease, assembleRelease are showing similar output.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating packages in `pubspec.yaml` by running `flutter pub upgrade`.

Comment: Can you update question with result of ```flutter doctor``` ?

Comment: All are accepted. Something is definitely wrong with the commandline tools